# Selecting WMS layers from GeoServer in OpenLayers application?

Tags: openlayers, wms, layers

I am making a weather application and I am almost there!

I can show my GeoServer WMS-layers in my browser using OpenLayers 5. What I want to accomplish is that the user can switch between different types of 'weather'. (The user can choose if it wants to see the wind, the rain or solar for example.)

How can I achieve this?

At the moment I made GeoServer group layers for all the different weather types. With a map baselayer and then the weather specific layers on top of that.

But how do I make the user choose what to see?

With some sort of menu in the corner.

I presume I have to do this in OpenLayers 5 and not GeoServer, but surely one of both has to have the ability to do this. I can't really find it myself.

Comment: There are two ways you could do it.  One is to create a separate OpenLayers layer for each WMS layer.  You could switch between them using any of the third party layer switchers available for OpenLayers.  The second is to use a single OpenLayers layer for your WMS and switch between the WMS layers using the updateParams method on the OpenLayers source, which would require your own switching menu.

Comment: Thank you. I searched for third party layer switchers and found this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol-layerswitcher#parcel-webpack-etc. I will try to make this work :)

Comment: Hee @Mike (or anybody else who reads this) I want to try to make it work with the updateParams, because the switchers that are available are not quite working for the application I build. But I can't really find a good example of how to use the updateParams. I can only find that it exists and what it should do but not how to use it. You know where I could find an example maybe?

Comment: Here's an example with updateParams in use, although it's being called automatically because the WMS parameters change at each zoom level http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/ol5-os-map-basic-wms.htm

Comment: If you were able to find a solution based on the suggestions provided, please consider writing an answer to your question. This will help other site users with the same question.

Comment: Almost there. When I have the final solution I will post it here :)